# Displaying logged tickets for CompanyX when user with role X is logged in

Tags: laravel-5

I am setting up an app where citizens can log tickets online to companies registered on our app. We have 5 types of User Roles

```
- [ App Super Admin, App Admin & App Support User ]
  ** Must see all logged tickets for all companies
- [ Company Admin & Company Support User ]
  ** Must see only tickets for their company
- [ App User ]
  ** Must see only their own logged tickets
```

Problem is that I see all tickets for all companies, irrespective of which user is logged-in.

I want the logged-in Company Support user or Company Admin to see only tickets logged for their company only and the app user who logged the ticket to only see their own tickets.

```
    {
        $companyUser = companyUser::findOrfail($user);

        if (Auth::user()->id = $companyUser) {
            $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
                ->join('company_users', 'company_users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                ->join('tickets', 'ticket.company_id', '=', 'company_users.company_id')
                ->select(
                    'tickets.ref_no',
                    'tickets.service_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_subject_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_status_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_priority_id',
                    'tickets.company_id',
                    'tickets.user_id',
                    'tickets.created_at'
                )
                ->where('company_users.user_id = users.id')
                ->get();
        } else {
            $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
                ->join('company_users', 'tickets.company_id', '=', 'company_users.company_id')
                ->select(
                    'tickets.ref_no',
                    'tickets.service_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_subject_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_status_id',
                    'tickets.ticket_priority_id',
                    'tickets.company_id',
                    'tickets.user_id',
                    'tickets.created_at'
                )
                ->groupBy('ref_no')
                ->get();
        }
```

Comment: Managed to solve it by filtering using their roleid and the where statement